# Audio Progress bar not working in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, audio

I'm playing audio on page load when user clicks on any location on browser in angular

```
<audio id="rsplayer">
<source src='{{ Url }}' />
</audio>
```

calling it using this code

```
  var player = <HTMLAudioElement> document.querySelector('#rsplayer');
      player.load();
      var promise = player.play();

      if (promise !== undefined) {
        promise.then(_ => {
     
        }).catch(error => {

        });
      }
```

audio is being played but the the progress bar and timer are not working.

Answer (score 0):

probably because changeDetecion isn't triggered.
this should help:
`player.onprogress = () => { this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); }`

Comment: Thanks i tried this but it is not working

Comment: how do you display the progrss bar value? like this: `{{player?.currentTime}}`

Comment: I'm using the default audio player right now, will default player work because i want to play the audio on page load when page load user clicks on popup and then audio starts playing